# How to manage two different production environments while migrating from Heroku to VPS (Digital Ocean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, vps

I have a live, functioning Rails app that is currently running on Heroku. In order to scale back on costs, I'm in the process of migrating the whole app to Digital Ocean. Much of what I've done so far has only involved adding extra gems and files to support Capistrano deployment, but I just ran into the first (presumably of many) instance where I need a different configuration for my app on Digital Ocean vs. what I use for Heroku. Specifically it's Redis. On Heroku you need to use an add-on ("Redis To Go") since you can't install Redis directly. Thus my reds_init.rb looks like this:

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  redis_conf_path = Rails.root.join("config/redis", "#{Rails.env}.conf")
  redis_conf = File.read(redis_conf_path)
  port = /port.(\d+)/.match(redis_conf)[1]
  `redis-server #{redis_conf_path}`
  REDIS = Redis.new(:port => port)
end

if Rails.env.production?
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
  REDIS = Redis.new(:url => ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])
end
```

That `production` configuration is Heroku-specific and for Digital Ocean I'll be needing something a lot more like (perhaps exactly like) the test/development configuration. However, during the migration I need to have both working as I may need to deploy code (bug fixes etc) to the live production environment while slowly setting up the Digital Ocean environment.

Since there will likely be many other instances of this sort of thing as I work through this migration, I'm thinking that the best way to handle this would be a separate Git branch for the Digital Ocean environment. But I'm not entirely sure the best way to set this up. I'd really appreciate any pointers from someone who's had to do a migration like this on a live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my thoughts with a general outline of the approach I've taken in the past:

1. For good measure, make sure your production environment is stable (tests passing) and preferably deployed off of the master branch on git. You'll want to be able to reliably deploy hotfixes on master as well as cross-reference any future changes during your migration with your development environment. Backup your DB as well.
2. Create and checkout a new git branch for digital ocean.
3. Create a new Rails configuration environment or digital ocean preferably with a name consistent with your branch name in (2). Make sure your new environment is isolated from what you're using in production. In other words, you shouldn't be able to "contaminate" your production environment from your new environment. This means all db & api connections use separate credentials. Also try to keep version control in mind with commits tracking specific changes. This will make debugging easier through `git bisect` if necessary.
4. Configure and test deployment of your application server on digital ocean using data in a seed database. Make sure you can perform all aspects of deployment, including running migrations, asset precompiling, bundler, stability of nginx/unicorn without affecting the stability of the site.
5. Take snapshots of your production database(s) on Heroku and import them into the database you're using on Digital Ocean. Again test your site and make sure it's working properly with production data.
6. Schedule a time when you can take your site offline for enough time to do the migration. You'll need to move DNS, DB data, environment configurations, and whatever other environment specific data.

Since your master branch should be stable, you can always go back to it to deploy bugfixes as necessary. However, make sure you incorporate (git cherry-pick) these commits into whatever branches are ahead of master for consistency. I'd recommend checkout out git-flow if you haven't already: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/.

This is mostly just food for thought as there's a lot to be said about the subject of migrating an application between data center. Specific approaches and strategies are going to depend on your dev ops setup and application environment.

Comment: Wow. That's awesome and much more than I was expecting. My focus for the time being is on step 3 so I have a few questions. First, to confirm, it sounds like the way to go is to use a separate branch for all the migration work, and that means I'd want to be testing the deploy process to DO off a non-master branch until things are resolved, correct? Second, I have my "droplet" created already, and I'm assuming that's what you mean by the configuration environment, yes? And that will still be the `production` configuration in my rails config files yes?

Comment: `master` should always be in a stable, deployable state. That is, the state of your code that's actively in production. By config environment I mean all the variables and configuration that are required for your app to run in a particular deployment. Some of this lives in Rails (such as which DB to connect to) some of it doesn't (eg DNS settings). I'd recommend creating a new *Rails* environment other than production.rb (eg "staging.rb") to make sure you're not crossing wires between your new setup and what you currently have on Heroku.